# SQLite limit to 5 records per sensor, replace oldest with newest

Tags: sql, sqlite

There have been similar(ish) questions, but this is a bit more specific...

I have 10 different sensors. I want to only keep the most recent 5 readings for each sensor.
The problem I am having is that when it reaches 5 readings, it will delete all the readings for that particular sensor and then start filling up again, until it reaches 5 again... and so on.
On reaching 5 readings, I want it to just "replace" the oldest with the newest. Been at this a while and can't fathom it out. I would prefer a reasonably easy-to-understand method as this is to help some kids who are creating a school project.
Thanks.

Here is the basic code so far...

## Python/SQL codeblock to delete the oldest entry for the given sensor and insert a new one (if greater than 5 readings)

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM readings WHERE Sensor IN (SELECT Sensor FROM readings WHERE Sensor = '%s' GROUP BY Sensor HAVING COUNT(Sensor)>5 and MIN(Timestamp))" % sensorName)
db.commit()
```

PS: I can see why it isn't working - it's because the SELECT statement is only going to select anything when the count is greater than 5, then it will delete all of the readings for that sensor, but I can't work out how to get it to only select the oldest and then delete that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this method will work in SQLite:

```
delete from readings
    where sensor = '%s' and
          timestamp not in (select r2.timestamp
                            from readings r2
                            where r2.sensor = readings.sensor
                            order by timestamp
                            limit 5
                           );
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I'm following you there. I don't get what all the r2 stuff is about. I'm basically trying to delete the oldest reading for each sensor. So I need to select only the oldest reading from each sensor for deletion. I can't understand why whoever invented SQL wouldn't make this kind of thing a bit easier!

Comment: This deletes all but the five oldest values.  I'm not sure if that is what you are asking for, however.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is for each sensor that has greater than 5 values, delete the oldest entry each time a new entry is inserted. The fields "Sensor", "Timestamp", "Temperature", "Humidity", "SensorID" are all in one table. There are 10 sensors that all send data into the same table, but under names "sensorOne", "sensorTwo", etc... thanks for the help. I think I'm just going to have to get a book and go back to basics, running before one can walk.